# Canvas position using printjs

Tags: javascript, positioning, html-to-pdf, printjs

I'm using printjs to convert my html page to pdf, all works fine except my canvas, which you can see here:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
printJS({
    printable: 'page1',
    type: 'html',
    scanStyles: false,
    ignoreElements: ['btnPrint'],
    css: [
        'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css',
        'css/sb-admin-2.min.css',
        'css/custom.css'
    ]
});
```

canvas height: 320px and width: 562px

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try to increase canvas height.
and Also adjust the center of this shape properly. looks like coordinates (x,y) are going out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to increase the canvas height with `canvas {height: 320;}` (i have only 1 canvas so it should be ok) with 320, 200, 300, even 1000 nothing changes this is my code

```js
printJS(
{printable:'page1', 
type:'html', 
scanStyles: false, 
ignoreElements:['btnPrint'], 
css: ['vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css', 'css/sb-admin-2.min.css', 'css/nowa.css'], 
style: ['@page { size: A4; margin: 0mm;} body {margin: 0;} canvas {height: 1000;}'], targetStyles: ['*']});
```

the @page and body works fine but even if i try to set background-color to red nothing changes.

I can center it by changing left: but cant use smt like `text-align: center` it doesn't work also.
I'am not really good at css so maybe it is not how to center a canvas i don't know.